# AureliaJS output a full path route in a view

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I understand how to push a route with route-href in the view and do router.generate in the TS code, but how do I output the full router path in a view?

I have code in the view like so:

```
<a route-href="route:profile; params.bind:{username:model.profile.username}">
    <span${router.generate...i want full path here for user}</span>
</a>
```

I am still looking at the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, for a route named 'inner', the expression could be:

```
<a route-href="route: inner">${router.generate("inner", {}, { absolute: true })}</a>
```

The absolute parameter tells the method to generate the full URL.

For a working example, see
https://gist.dumber.app/?gist=fbfa0f97fdaa0ecb99408d89c4680550

Regards,

Cristian